# Is this a valid proof of Well-definedness?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module, injective-module

We are given $L, M$ and $N$ as unitary $R$-modules, and $f:M\rightarrow N$ as an isomorphism. We need to prove that $f^*:Hom_R(N,L)\rightarrow Hom_R(M,L)$ is an isomorphism.

I started by defining the function f$^*$ this way:
We have f$^*$(g) = gof for any g$\in$Hom$_R$(N,L). Consider the diagram below:

[image]

Obviously, the diagram commutes. Since g and f are R-module homomorphisms, then gof is an R-module homomorphism. We have gof $\in$ Hom$_R(M,L)$. Hence, $f^*(g) = gof is well-defined.

My question is, is this okay? Did I do justice to the well-definedness of the function? I have the feeling that I didn’t do a good job here, but I don’t know what to do. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Is this Proof of Valid?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: Please see edits I made on using $s correctly to typeset your math.  I left some still to edit.  Also it is discouraged to use pictures for a variety of reasons unless essential (e.g. a geometric picture or graph). Commutative diagrams are possible in MathJax.

Comment: You have defined it and explained why it is an $R$-module homomorphism.  Does that prove it is an isomorphism?

Comment: @AlgTop1854 No, it doesn’t. I have proved the isomorphism part. I am not just confident about the well-definedness part.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks for the feedback. I just edited the title. I hope this is better.

Comment: Ok I see, you only needed help with this part.  You should have said that!  I think you are fine then.   Being well-defined usually is more specific to the case of defining something on equivalence classes, where you need to make sure that if two points belong to that same class they are mapped to the same point.  Here I think you just wanted to make sure you defined $f^*$ correctly, which you have.  You could go as far as saying that $f^*g(n)=(g \circ f)(n)$ for any $g\in Hom_R(N,L)$ and any $n\in N$.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Did you mean f$^*$(g(n)) = (gof)(m) for any g$\in$Hom$_R$(N,L), n$\in$N and m$\in$M?

Comment: Yes, I believe I did - and I can't edit any more so thank you.  These are not hard but you can see it is easy to get tripped up.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 And thanks for the feedback on the image. I will give that a try one of these days.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 (and @MrProf) : I believe that it should be $f^*(g)(m)=(g(f(m))$ for any $g\in\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,L)$ and any $m\in M$. In other words, $f^*(g)=g\circ f$, so $f^*$ is applied to $g$ and then $f^*(g)$ is applied to $m$, not $f^*$ applied to $g(m)$. (Although a lot of people would write $f^*g$ instead of $f^*(g)$.) And there is no arbitrary $n\in N$; we have only $f(m)\in N$ along the way.

Comment: I agree, and clearly I bollixed it up the first time (and un-editable now but if I delete context of other comments is lost). Thx.